# which consensus algorithm is synchronous in nature?

Tags: algorithm, blockchain, consensus

There are different consensus algorithm, which are used in permission-oriented blockchain, such as

1. PAXOS
2. RAFT
3. Byzantine General Model

Which of the consensus algorithms are synchronous and asynchronous and why ? Please explain in detail.
Thanks

Comment: Define what you mean by these terms. In general, replication of data is synchronous (and must be), but the underlying transports can be asynchronous.

Answer (score 4):

*I am not an expert on distributed systems still i will try to answer your question.

In distributed systems, People use an underlying model that assumes some properties about time (“how long will it take for this message to arrive?”) and some properties about the types of faults (“how can nodes in the protocol do the wrong thing?”).

There are three main types of timing models usually used for distributed systems the synchronous model, the asynchronous model and the partially synchronous model. Each of these models makes some guarantees about the length of time (“latency”) that can occur between the exchange of messages amongst nodes in a given round of the protocol execution. This categorization is important because in the distributed setting a single node cannot distinguish between a peer node that has failed and a peer node that is just taking a long time to respond.

In the synchronous model, there is some maximum value (“upper bound”) T on the time between when a node sends a message and when you can be certain that the receiving node hears the message. You also have an upper bound P on the relative difference in speed between nodes (so you can account for machines with slow processors).

In the asynchronous model, we remove both upper bounds T and P. Messages can take arbitrarily long to reach peers and each node can take an arbitrary amount of time to respond. When we say arbitrary, we include “infinity” meaning that it takes forever for some event to occur.

The partially synchronous model in a mix of the two: upper bounds exist for T and P but the protocol designer does not know them and the task is designing mechanisms that still come to consensus in light of this fact. In practice, protocol implementers can achieve systems resembling this model given the realistic characteristics of modern networks/machines (messages usually get where they are going) and use of tactics like timeouts to indicate when a node should retry sending a message.

Keeping in mind the above facts, Both Paxos and Raft belongs to the partial synchronous models.

The Byzantine Generals’ Problem is a classic problem faced by any distributed computer system network. Aim is to maintain same state on all participant nodes in presence of malicious nodes.

In distributed systems, there a collection of hard problems that you constantly need to deal with.

```
 Things fail. You can never count on anything being reliable. Even if you have
 perfectly bug-free software, and hardware that never breaks, you’ve still got 
 to deal with the fact that network connections can break, or messages within a 
 network can get lost, or that some bozo might sever your network connection
 with a bulldozer. (That really happened while I was at Google!)

 Given (1), you can never rely on one copy of anything, because that copy might 
 become unavailable due to a failure. So you need to keep multiple copies, and
 those copies need to be consistent – meaning that at any time, all of the
 copies agree about their contents.

 There’s no way to maintain a single completely consistent view of time between
 multiple computers. Due to inconsistencies in individual machine performance,
 and variable network delays, variable storage latency, and several other
 factors, there’s no canonical way of saying that for two events X and Y, “X
 happened before Y”. What that means is that when you try to maintain a consistent set of data, you can’t just say “Run all of the events in order”, because while one server maintaining one copy might “know” that X happened before Y, another server maintaining another copy might be just as certain that Y happened before X.
```

In short, everything can fail at any time; after failure, participants can recover and rejoin the system; any no part of the system acts in an actively adversarial way(byzantine failures may be because of malware).

To solve this problem we have consensus algorithm with the aim to make all participants to agree on the same state.
Consensus involves multiple servers agreeing on values. Once they reach a decision on a value, that decision is final. Typical consensus algorithms make progress when any majority of their servers is available.
Paxos and Raft are consensus algorithms which solves byzantine general problem in distributed networks public or private.

Comment: thanks saurav, but it is still unclear to me. I did know that there are only 2 types of models - synchronous and asynchronous. after reading your answer I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks @GraphicalDot. It was very helpful for me. Have you write this reply from a reference?